# Captcha verification Python Django

Tags: python, django, captcha

I am getting Invalid captcha response for below set up. Contact form worked perfectly fine, I added rule that verifies captcha, I checked secret keys and still getting Invalid Captcha even after solving it. Below is my setup:

views.py

```
    def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

def grecaptcha_verify(request):
        response = {}
        data = request.POST
        captcha_rs = data.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
        params = {
            'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': captcha_rs,
            'remoteip': get_client_ip(request)
        }
        verify_rs = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=True)
        verify_rs = verify_rs.json()
        response["status"] = verify_rs.get("success", False)
        response['message'] = verify_rs.get('error-codes', None) or "Unspecified error."
        return response

def contact(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if grecaptcha_verify(request) == "success":
                subject = request.POST.get('subject')
                message = request.POST.get('message')
                email = request.POST.get('email')     
                if subject and message and email:
                    try:
                        send_mail(subject, message, email, ['myemail@gmail.com'],fail_silently= True)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('{Bad Header}')
                    return greatsuccess(request)        
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('{Invalid Form}')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Captcha')    
        return render(request, 'personal/contact.html')
```

My template:

```
 <div class="form-area">  
        <form role="form" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="300" rows="7"></textarea>                
                    </div>

        <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-m btn-secondary">Submit</button>

        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MYKEY"></div>

        </form>
```

I am quite new to Python, how to check what is happening in the background and at which point verification fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making `get` request for verification, but you need to make `post` request to it. That is why captcha verification failing. So try like this:

```
    url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'DebuguearApi-Browser',}
    params = {'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, 'response': captcha_rs}
    verify_rs = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)  # <--  Update Here
    ... # rest of your code
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) on how to verify recaptcha.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I've changed that, I also change a code a little bit so that it spits out google's response. I am getting "missing-input-response". I can't seem to figure out at which point it happens.

Comment: Same msg as response.

Comment: according to documentation, it seems that the request is malformed. Can you check if `captcha_rs` is getting proper value or not. also I have updated my answer slightly, please check if it works or not.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I am not sure how to view if captcha_rs has proper value. I don't see it in Eclipse console. How would I go about it ?

Comment: just use `print(captcha_rs)`

Comment: It prints it as None. It looks like it can't find g-recaptcha-response in post data. I checked it and form only returns subject/msg/body and csrf_token.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
I got it working. Thanks Ruddra for all the help.

I deleted first  `</div>` as I've noticed this was unnecessary. This allowed g-recaptcha-response to be included in POST data. Apparently it's important to make sure your form is correct and google likes it.

Secondly I did some modifications to main views.py as per advice I received+ some improvements.

```
def greatsuccess(request):
    messages.success(request, "Email sent!")
    return render(request, 'personal/contact.html')

def greatfail(request):
    messages.error(request, "Invalid Captcha!")
    return render(request, 'personal/contact.html')

def grecaptcha_verify(request):
        data = request.POST
        captcha_rs = data.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'DebuguearApi-Browser',}
        params = {'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, 'response': captcha_rs}
        verify_rs = requests.post(url,params, headers=headers)
        verify_rs = verify_rs.json()
        response = verify_rs.get("success", False)
        return response 

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response=grecaptcha_verify(request)
        if response == True :
            subject = request.POST.get('subject')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            email = request.POST.get('email')     
            if subject and message and email:
                try:
                        send_mail('Sent from mywebsite '+subject, message, email, ['email@gmail.com'],fail_silently= True)
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('{Bad Header}')
                return greatsuccess(request)        
            else:
                    return HttpResponse('{Invalid Form}')
        else:
            greatfail(request)
    return render(request, 'personal/contact.html')
```

My template:

```
<form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="70" required>

                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="300" rows="7"></textarea>                
                    </div>

                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>

                    <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-m btn-secondary">Submit</button>

        </form>

    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
```